# How to get URL of currently opened tab in Internet Explorer with apex code

Tags: tab, url, browser

I want to get all the URL of currently opened tabs in my apex class. If anyone can guide a bit or have little knowledge how to make it possible, Please let me know.

Comment: Why `Apex`? That context doesn't even make any sense for this question.

Comment: That's definitely something client side .. but I would imagine browsers don't expose that information as it would probably be a security issue.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get all the tabs, only the current one. For that, you can try using this: `ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl()`

More information [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_PageReference_methods.htm)

Comment: That will only get the current tab though, the question was for all the open tabs which presumably can include anything that is in the browser.

Comment: Ooops. Read the title and not the text. Amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that this just isn't possible. Apex is completely separate from the browser. Apex has no knowledge of the client's environment.

Getting client information (and then passing that information to something like an Apex controller extension) requires Javascript. That's a gross oversimplification but, that said, Javascript doesn't have that kind of access either.

This would be a huge security issue if it were possible.